# Xcode iOS Universal application Image sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to create `universal application for all iOS devices` (iPhone and iPad). Now i am confused by Image size processing. give me a `@1x , 2x, 3x` Image size process and details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you know, there are multiple iOS devices available in the marketplace, such as iPhone 4, iPhone 4s, iPhone 5, iPhone 5s, iPhone 6, iPhone 6+, iPad, iPad Retina and so forth.

These devices have different resolutions where the newer devices (such as iPhone 6 and iPad Retina) have higher resolutions and older devices (such as iPhone 4) have lower resolutions.

For an image, the **@1x**, **@2x** and **@3x** placeholders in an image asset allows you to provide:

1. a *low* resolution image which maps to **@1x**,
2. a *mid* resolution image which maps to **@2x**, and
3. a *high* resolution image which maps to **@3x**.

Therefore, in a universal app, the **@1x / low resolution image** for your icon, for example, will be used automatically for the iPhone 4 devices while your **@3x / high resolution image** will be used for the iPhone 6 devices.

For my universal apps, I take my various PNG images and scale them according to [Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) in Apple's [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH66-SW1) documentation.

For example, if I have an ***App Icon*** image then I will create three different copies of that image in three different size:

1. The low resolution @1x version at 76 x 76.
2. The mid resolution @2x version at 120 x 120.
3. The high resolution @3x version at 180 x 180.

If you are using a storyboard then you can drag and drop the relevant image into the corresponding 1x/2x/3x image assets position for the image.

Again, refer to Apple's Human and User Interface guidelines to get a feel for an approximate image size that you want to target for the various assets (i.e., App icon, Launch image, Settings icon, Tab bar icon, etc).

Answer (score 2):

There is an image naming convention for the devices.
Please check below apple doc for more refrences-
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH7-SW17

use '~iphone' for iPhone images and no suffix for iPad. You may use '~iPad' for iPad images.

**MyImage.png** - Default version of an image resource.

**MyImage@2x.png** - High-resolution version of an image resource for devices with Retina displays.

**MyImage~iphone.png** - Version of an image for iPhone and iPod touch.

**MyImage@2x~iphone.png** - High-resolution version of an image for iPhone and iPod touch devices with Retina displays.